# Ubuntu 20.04 github, vs-code. https protocol PAT was used

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-20.04

git command started to fail today with it was set to use https protocol with personal access token (i double checked it is not expired)

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (GitHub.UI.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'HarfBuzzSharp.NativeAssets.Linux', version: '2.6.1.7'
    path: 'runtimes/linux-x64/native/libHarfBuzzSharp.so'
fatal: helper error (140): Unknown
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/.....git/'
```

but it used to work just fine yesterday.
Some automatic update had happen yesterday night. What do i do now?

Comment: The "helper error" part means that Git ran a credential helper. You can configure *which* helper(s) Git will run for you. It's not clear to me which one actually did run here, but whichever one it was, it died a horrible death and Git then said: oops, don't know how to proceed. You need to find out which helper you're using—it's probably not part of Git itself; it looks fancy in its errors—and figure out what's wrong with it, or choose some other helper that's not going to fail.

Comment: I also get the same `Error` and `fatal` messages. I have `credential.credentialStore = cache` set in my gitconfig.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was a packagin error in a recent release of gcmcore: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/528

Downgrade version or download the missing .so files as stated in the link.

Comment: my experies with Linux (which just starting to build up) left me with only "reinstall everything" solustion. And it took only half an hour for me to start coding again. Wich is amazing by it self. Still learning